# Find the average of one variable in multiple year classes in R

Tags: r, plot

I have 50 year-classes, and age and length data on individuals within each year class. 
Without inputting a different data set for each year class I'm trying to plot average age for each year class.

As in year class along the x axis and average age (or length) (for each year class) along the y.

This is my data frame

```
'data.frame':   236628 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ maturity: Ord.factor w/ 2 levels "0"<"1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year    : Factor w/ 50 levels "1966","1967",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ quarter : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ area    : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ lngth   : int  145 145 145 150 150 150 150 150 155 155 ...
 $ age     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sex     : Ord.factor w/ 2 levels "0"<"1": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
```

Cheers

Comment: `plot(aggregate(lngth~year, data=dat, FUN=mean))`, though you might want to convert `year` from a factor to a numeric value first.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much!
Is there a way I could add average length at age into the code for the plot? For example the average length at age 2 for each year class?

Comment: or any other variables for that matter
e.g. average length at age 2, area 1, quarter 3 and male.
I'm bet this is all relatively simple stuff but I just can't fathom it!
Cheers.

Comment: Just aggregate on a subset of the data. For your first example `plot(aggregate(lngth~year, data=dat[dat$age == 2,], FUN=mean))`

Comment: Thanks again for your help!
I have just asked a question re logistic regression models. I don't know if you could help me with this as well but you certainly know a lot more about coding in r than me!